# Async callback is called but not executed sometimes

Tags: c#, wcf, asynchronous

Silverlight project.

In my View code behind, I call a method in the View Model to get value.

```
 public MyViewModel ViewModel
    {
        get
        {
            if (this.viewModel == null)
                this.viewModel = new MyViewModel();
            return this.viewModel;
        }
        set
        {
            if (this.viewModel != value)
            {
                this.viewModel = value;
            }
        }
    }
```

However the async callback is not called. Sometimes it is called by delay. Thus I get the value as `1900-01-01 00:00:00.000` instead of the correct date time.

```
DateTime value;
public void GetDateTime()
    {
        var proxy = new WcfClient();
        proxy.GetCurrentDateTimeCompleted -= ProxyGetCurrentDateTimeCompleted;
        proxy.GetCurrentDateTimeCompleted += ProxyGetCurrentDateTimeCompleted;
        proxy.GetCurrentDateTimeAsync();
    }

    private void ProxyGetCurrentDateTimeCompleted(object sender, GetCurrentDateTimeCompletedEventArgs args)
    {
        try
        {
            value = args.Result;
```

To call it in code behind.

```
this.viewModel.GetDateTime();
```

**Update 1**

Upon the comment, I added some explanation. The View has a checkbox. If I click it or unclick it, a message box with Yes/No button will pop up. Whatever you select Yes or No, I will record the date and time in the `MessageBoxYesNoSelection_Closed` event. The event method is still in the code behind.

The checkbox part code is:

```
if (clickedCheckBox != null)
{
    var msgBoxControl = new MessageBoxControl();
    msgBoxControl.Closed -= MessageBoxYesNoSelection_Closed;
    msgBoxControl.Closed += MessageBoxYesNoSelection_Closed;

    if (clickedCheckBox.IsChecked == true)
    {
        var curDateTime = this.ViewModel.value;// 1900-01-01 00:00:00.000
```

Inside `MessageBoxYesNoSelection_Closed`, we get the value.

```
this.ViewModel.GetDateTime();// WCF async call
this.ViewModel.UpdateValue(value); // another WCF async call, need value from GetDateTime() method's return result.
this.ViewModel.UpdateAnotherValue(value, user); // third WCF async call
```

What I found is sometimes the async callbacks are not executed although they are called.

Comment: You need to provide more information about how you are getting the value `value` after the async function is done, you need to provide a [Minimal Complete Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), right now you have left out too much information for us to effectively help you.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain, thanks for the comment. I added some codes.

Comment: Set a breakpoint in your Service-Class and watch what's happening there. Does the server receive the request? Is the timeout too short? A lotta guessing for me...

Comment: @lokusking, the server did receive the request. The thing is sometimes I can get the correct value, sometimes not.

Comment: *Sometimes* indicate a timeout issue on some circumstances. Is your Server-Method surrounded with a `lock`?

Comment: @lokusking. The answer is no.

Comment: yes, sometimes the server doesn't receive the request.I checked the timeout on server side. It is 00:10:00. I changed the client side Timeout setting as [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17334368/wcf-in-silverlight-how-to-set-change-the-default-timeout-of-1-minute). But is still same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess that you are experiencing a [race condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition#Software), as you are not awaiting the `this.ViewModel.GetDateTime()` call and therefore in most cases the callback that sets the value (`ProxyGetCurrentDateTimeCompleted`) has not been called before you are using the value in the next statement (`this.ViewModel.UpdateValue(value)`).

The easiest solution would be to use `async` & `await` as described [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt674882.aspx) and [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/endpoint/2010/11/12/simplified-asynchronous-programming-model-in-wcf-with-asyncawait/).

If you can't do that another solution would be to move the code that depends on the value into the callback method.

#### Update 1

There is a possibility to use `async` & `await` with Silverlight 4 and .NET Framework 4.0. See [Microsoft.Bcl.Async](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Async) for more information. However, this method requires at least Visual Studio 2012, so in case you can't switch to a newer Visual Studio version this won't work for you.

In that case the idea would be to move the code dependent on the value into the callback method. So at first you would only call `GetDateTime()`:

```
this.ViewModel.GetDateTime(); // WCF async call
```

Then you'll call the other methods in the callback method:

```
private void ProxyGetCurrentDateTimeCompleted(object sender, GetCurrentDateTimeCompletedEventArgs args)
{
    value = args.Result;
    UpdateValue(value); // another WCF async call, need value from GetDateTime()
    UpdateAnotherValue(value, user); // third WCF async call
}
```

#### Update 2

Following your last comment, I would recommend you to restructure your application so that you can use an approach as shown in the first update. Storing data in the code behind and the view model seems a bit odd. However, if you want a quick solution you could also wait for the callback to set the value manually. See the following code as example to get you started:

```
DateTime value;
bool wcfCallInProgress;
public void GetDateTime()
{
    var proxy = new WcfClient();
    proxy.GetCurrentDateTimeCompleted -= ProxyGetCurrentDateTimeCompleted;
    proxy.GetCurrentDateTimeCompleted += ProxyGetCurrentDateTimeCompleted;
    wcfCallInProgress = true;
    proxy.GetCurrentDateTimeAsync();
}

private void ProxyGetCurrentDateTimeCompleted(object sender, GetCurrentDateTimeCompletedEventArgs args)
{
    value = args.Result;
    wcfCallInProgress = false;
}
```

Now you can add a loop which waits until the value has been set:

```
this.ViewModel.GetDateTime();// WCF async call

while (this.ViewModel.wcfCallInProgress)
{
    Thread.Sleep(10);
}

this.ViewModel.UpdateValue(value); // another WCF async call, need value from GetDateTime() method's return result.
this.ViewModel.UpdateAnotherValue(value, user); // third WCF async call
```

If you use this approach you'll have to make sure that timeouts and exceptions won't be a problem. Otherwise you may end up with an infinite loop.

Comment: I use Visual Studio 2010, .NET 4. async & await is .NET 4.5.

Comment: Then I guess you have to change your code to ensure that the `UpdateValue(value)` and `UpdateAnotherValue(value, user)` methods are called after the `ProxyGetCurrentDateTimeCompleted` callback was called. The easiest way to ensure that would be to to call these methods in the callback method after you set the value.

Comment: I agree with your idea. Now the question is how to ensure these methods are called in proper order. I even put one method in the finally block but still not working.

Comment: I've added an example. If the third WCF async call requires a value from the second WCF call you have to move it into the callback handler from the second call (and so on).

Comment: The thing is as I said,  `if (clickedCheckBox != null)` is in code behind. In the ViewModel I call WCF. So they are in the different places. Therefore I have to pass checkbox and messagebox information to it as well, also I have other parameters such as user etc. to pass in WCF call.

Comment: I've added another update. In addition I've noticed that you are using the value in the checkbox part of you code (`var curDateTime = this.ViewModel.value;`) and I don't see a call to GetDateTime() before you use the value. If you are relying on `MessageBoxYesNoSelection_Closed` to set the value you might have another race condition.

Comment: I used your first update. The first two wcf calls seem to be okay. I put the second owcg call inside the first wcf completed method. But the third one is not working. I put the third one into the second one's completed method instead of the first one. Maybe the proxy is not closed?

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea :-/

Comment: Ignore my previous comment. The question is here: ` this.ViewModel.GetHoldDateTime();
                curDateTime = this.ViewModel.value;` The completed method has not finished, then curDateTime returns the default time. Inside the completed method, `value = args.Result;`. It is not correct.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for.